# 45 Minute Layover in Frankfurt on a flight from the US to India. Do I need to rebook?

Tags: short-connections, fra

I booked a flight from the US to India which has a 45 minute layover in Frankfurt. I'm a decently experienced flier and I've handled one hour layovers in Abu Dhabi or half an hour layovers domestically, but this one is freaking me out quite a bit.

The tickets are on one booking from Lufthansa and both flights arrive and take off from the same Terminal - Terminal 1. My one concern is that any outbound flights from Frankfurt to India would require me to have a Schengen visa, which I don't. Re-booking the flight would probably double the flight time.

Do you think I will be able to make my flight? Has anyone experienced this before?

Also, I'm flying in a from a non-Schengen zone area to another. I believe there are other implications as a result.

Comment: Quite possibly there's only one flight a day and OP doesn't want to spend 24 hours in the terminal and checking into a hotel requires entering into the Schengen zone.

Comment: Also, if I get a flight, it might just be going to Munich, which to the best of my knowledge, requires a Schengen visa.

Comment: Please post your full itinerary for that flight (with flight numbers).

Comment: Yeah, Visa / Immigration into either US or India is not an issue. 

My itinerary is:

SJC 03:30 PM -> FRA 11:50 AM
FRA 12:35 PM -> BOM 01:00 AM

Do you think I can make that?

Comment: Folks, this is a not a duplicate of the other question. The other traveller was coming from a Schengen zone into Frankfurt, which I believe has a different immigration process than what I have. Please correct this.

Comment: Fully agree with OP here and have voted to reopen.

Comment: If your particular concern is what @chx describes above, you might want to edit your question to make this explicit. Your _chances of making the connection_ will be better than for a Schengen-to-non-Schengen connection of the same length (since you won't need to pass any immigration entry/exit checks), but the _consequences of not making it_ could be worse.